# Change font used in Android Studio (the IDE, not in apps)

Tags: android-studio

How can I change the font used by Android studio?  Worked just switched me to a windows 10 pc from a mac and the font in AS is just too small and thin for my eyes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate to File>Settings>Appearance and then check the checkbox `Override default font by` in image and change the defaults.
[image]